# Bound properties are not updated when navigating to page

Tags: angular

When I navigate to my control by clicking on a link the page (the bound properties) is sometimes not updated.  Usually it is the first time I click on a link.  Subsequent clicks work fine.  Browser reports no errors.  Breakpoints in code show that code is executing normally.
This smells like a timing issue.  Am I handling the correct event?  Perhaps related to: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7576

When I navigate to my control by typing or pasting a url in the browser the page is never updated. Browser reports no errors.  Breakpoints in code show that code is executing normally.

blogDetail.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'blog-blog-detail',
    templateUrl: './app/blog/blogDetail.html'
})
export class BlogDetail {
    PostRoot = this.sessionService.PostRoot;
    private Post: ContentItem;
    private Content: string;
    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private blogService: BlogService) {
        this.Post = new ContentItem();
        this.Content = "";
    }

    routerOnActivate(data: RouteSegment)
    {
        let slug = data.getParam('slug');

        if (slug === null || typeof slug === 'undefined')
            return;

        this.blogService.GetContentItemBySlug(slug, this.sessionService.CurrentSite.ID).subscribe(x => {
            this.Post = x;
            this.blogService.GetPostHtml(this.sessionService.PostRoot  + this.Post.URL).subscribe((h: string) => {
                this.Content = h;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

blogDetail.html

```
<div>
    <h1>this is blog detail</h1>
    {{Post.Title}}
    <div [innerHTML]="[Content]"></div>
</div>
```

Revised per Arpits comment:

```
routerOnActivate(data: RouteSegment)
{
    let slug = data.getParam('slug');

    if (slug === null || typeof slug === 'undefined')
        return;

    this.Post = this.blogService.GetContentItemBySlug(slug, this.sessionService.CurrentSite.ID);


    //.subscribe(x => {
    //    this.Post = x;
    //    this.blogService.GetPostHtml(this.sessionService.PostRoot  + this.Post.URL).subscribe((h: string) => {
    //        this.Content = h;
    //    });
    //});

    this.Post.subscribe(x => { // null error here
        this.Content = this.blogService.GetPostHtml(this.sessionService.PostRoot + x.URL);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try using async pipe in template  {{POST.Title | async }}

Comment: Thx Arpit, can you plz see my change above and tell me how  to wait on this.Post to be set before attempting to set this.Content?  see "null error here" comment.

Comment: If `post` is aquired from a service (async) then `{{Post?.Title}}` should do it. It should produce an error though. Still worth a try I guess.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal sorry it does not work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried your suggestion but it does not work.  I've seen other examples on Stackoverflow and I cannot tell what I am doing wrong.  Please point me in the right direction to get this working, thx.